# IE 7 Splitting and Dropping SPAN element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Good afternoon!

This is a strange IE 7 issue that I've yet to come across.  On IE 7, it is removing the "Us" portion of the About Us and Contact Us Span elements and dropping it below the navigation bar.  I tried to post a screenshot but I need to work on my reputation (street cred?) before I'm allowed to.   I've tried a number of things, but I can't seem to find the root of the problem.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

http://www.indianbrookgolf.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a non braking space (`&nbsp;`) between the About and Us?

Alternatively, have you tried the following CSS rule for the specific element?

```
nb.span { white-space: nowrap; }
```

A non breaking space, or   tells the browser not to break white spaces... the bit between the About and Us in your case. Glad it helped

Comment: It's created dynamically, so I'm afraid I can't edit the text within the span. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes! That did it.  Can you please explain why that was necessary?

Comment: Only after you mark the question answered :P

But seriously.... a non breaking space, or &nbsp; tells the browser not to break white spaces... the bit between the About and Us in your case.

Glad it helped

Comment: Ah, I see.  So the white-space property can do the same thing as adding a non-breaking space within the html.